# Highest throughput write pattern for windowed events

Tags: mongodb

We have an IoT device that will send in sensor readings when a user interacts with the device.  The user will typically interact with the device multiple times with each interaction generating a sensor reading.  The device will then transmit each sensor reading to a backend API but order and timeliness are not guaranteed.

On the backend API we must window all sensor readings into a single event that happened within the same 2 minutes and timestamp the event with the timestamp of the first event in the window.  Due to not having order or timeliness guarantees from the IoT device we currently have a schema where each user has a document per day and an array of events that in turn has an array of the sensor readings.  We currently query this whole document on every sensor reading and in application code determine the correct events based on the existing sensor readings and the new one just received.

We've seen some performance and locking issues having to query the entire document and process this event windowing in application code and save the entire document.  Is there a way to do this event windowing completely in mongodb? What is the pattern that would give us the highest write throughput overall.

Comment: Why not document per window?

Comment: Because if we receive a new sensor reading that changes the bounds of the windows we might have to rewrite multiple documents. I'm not saying it's not the right solution but that's a downside.

Comment: Lock contention is usually tied to heavy write activity. I agree with @SergioTulentsev that you should explore saving this data at a finer granularity. Rewriting multiple documents that cover an multiple minute time space will likely be cheaper than writing a much larger document that encompasses data for the entire day.

Comment: Is there a way to not rewrite a bigger doc and just do an update with an $setOnInsert? Wouldn't an update path have a higher write throughput then a doc per event insert path?